# How to convert varchar field to date format in crystal reports?

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-2010

I have a field 'DOB' where it is of type varchar in mysql.I get output in the format of 1989/09/24 00:00:00.000 when i select the statement.I get the same in crystal reports.I need to convert it into  format of  sep 09,1989.I am not finding how to do it in the formula editor.help me out regarding this.thanks...

Comment: Please try using DateValue(columnName) in your formula and let me know what output you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, which first takes the varchar and removes the space and the time stamp after the date and then coverts what is left to an actual date. Once that is done you can format the field anyway that Crystal allows.

```
CDate(Left({YourDateField}, Instr(1, {YourDateField}, " ") - 1))
```

Just replace the YourDateField with the field you are trying to convert.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the date format mysql itself through below query.

```
SELECT date_Format('1989/09/24', '%Y/%m/%d');
```

Comment: Hi Dhinakaran Pragasam,I need it in crytsal reports.what you gave will only work in sql selection but not in formula editor of crystal reports...:(

Comment: @Friend I don't know crystal report. refer this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/DateFormatInCR06132007092248AM/DateFormatInCR.aspx